# weird thing happened when access list via a variable instead of constant

Tags: r, list

```
> a = 1:10
> a
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> a[1:5]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
> i = 1
> a[i:i+5]
[1] 6
```

who can tell me why values of `a[i:i+5]` not `1 2 3 4 5 6`

Thanks very much...

Comment: Precedence. Use `a[i:(i+5)]`.

Comment: As @Roland says it's precedence of operators. See `?Syntax`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because `i:i+5` is equivalent to `(i:i)+5`

```
i = 1
i:i + 5
## [1] 6
```

You should be using `i:(i+5)`

```
a[i:(i + 5)]
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Possibly, something is wrong with precedence operators.
try with

```
a[i:(i+5)]
```